# Переход между блоками (выделение содержимого) с помощью jquery, как исправить?

Tags: jquery

Извините за нубский вопрос, но помогите разобраться и подскажите как правильно это реализовать:

есть 3 блока, в которых заглавие, текст, цена, кнопка. 
При клике по кнопке определенного блока, меняется цвет заглавия, цены, и кнопки (я добавляю класс active), но при этом параметры меняются и у других блоков, как сделать так что бы при клике на кнопку данного блока менялись параметры только данного блока, при клике на кнопку у другого блока - параметры выделялись у другого блока

```js
$('.order-form').click(function() {
  $(".name, .price, .price .rub").removeClass("active");
  $(".name").toggleClass("active");
  $(".price, .price .rub").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.form-of-training {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgba(0, 0, 2, 0.08);
  padding: 45px 70px 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.name {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: gray;
  font-family: $MB;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.name.active {
  color: blue;
}
.text {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: $ML;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 75px;
}
.price {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: $MB;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.price.active {
  color: blue;
}
.rub {
  font-family: "ALSRubl", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: gray;
}
.rub.active {
  color: blue;
}
.order-form {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px 35px 6px 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: $ML;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  @include border-radius($radius: 4px);
  @include transition(background-color .6s);
  &: hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-of-training variant-one">
  <div class="name">Очная</div>
  <span class="text">36 академических часов,
                        занятия по будням или субботам</span>
  <span class="price">15 000<span class="rub">p</span></span>
  <button class="order-form">Заказать</button>
</div>
<div class="form-of-training variant-two">
  <div class="name">Заочная</div>
  <span class="text">Работа с преподавателем по e-mail</span>
  <span class="price">21 800<span class="rub">p</span></span>
  <button class="order-form">Заказать</button>
</div>
<div class="form-of-training variant-three">
  <div class="name">Экспресс-курс</div>
  <span class="text">В Черногории! 3 полных дня в учебном классе в городе Бар</span>
  <span class="price">270 &euro;</span>
  <button class="order-form">Заказать</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в том, что оно по клику сначала обращается к родителю кнопки `.form-of-training`, а потом к дочерним элементам этого родителя. Вот так вот

```js
$('.order-form').click(function() {
  $('.form-of-training').find(".name, .price, .price .rub").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parents('.form-of-training').find(".name").toggleClass("active");
  $(this).parents('.form-of-training').find(".price, .price .rub").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.form-of-training {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 370px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 24px rgba(0, 0, 2, 0.08);
  padding: 45px 70px 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.name {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: gray;
  font-family: $MB;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.name.active {
  color: blue;
}
.text {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: $ML;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  height: 75px;
}
.price {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: $MB;
  font-weight: 400;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.price.active {
  color: blue;
}
.rub {
  font-family: "ALSRubl", sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: gray;
}
.rub.active {
  color: blue;
}
.order-form {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 8px 35px 6px 35px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-family: $ML;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  @include border-radius($radius: 4px);
  @include transition(background-color .6s);
  &: hover {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-of-training variant-one">
  <div class="name">Очная</div>
  <span class="text">36 академических часов,
                        занятия по будням или субботам</span>
  <span class="price">15 000<span class="rub">p</span></span>
  <button class="order-form">Заказать</button>
</div>
<div class="form-of-training variant-two">
  <div class="name">Заочная</div>
  <span class="text">Работа с преподавателем по e-mail</span>
  <span class="price">21 800<span class="rub">p</span></span>
  <button class="order-form">Заказать</button>
</div>
<div class="form-of-training variant-three">
  <div class="name">Экспресс-курс</div>
  <span class="text">В Черногории! 3 полных дня в учебном классе в городе Бар</span>
  <span class="price">270 &euro;</span>
  <button class="order-form">Заказать</button>
</div>
```

Comment: все как бы отлично, но при клике на новый блок, остаются активными выделенные пункты предыдущего блока, а необходимо что бы активными были только текущие

Comment: @sagan, исправил

Comment: очень выручили, спасибо!!!

Comment: @sagan, суть в том, что оно по клику сначала обращается к родителю кнопки `.form-of-training`, а потом к дочерним элементам этого родителя

Comment: ну это я уже понял исходя из кода

Comment: @Yuri, объяснение нужно перенести из комментария в сам ответ

Comment: @Grundy, пардон, в следующий раз сделаем правильно)

Comment: @Yuri отредактировать свой ответ ты всегда можешь, нажав кнопку [edit] под ним

Comment: @Grundy, сделал, мистер зануда )